# is there unity method for scaling array values down or up to a given range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have an array of values
say [-5, 10 ,20]

and i want it to scale down to a range
say [0, 10]

i can do a function that can handle this but i am looking for a built in function in unity or c# that can perform the same job

here is what i did so far but it doesn't support negative values

```cs
    float[] arr = new float[] { 5f ,10f ,20f };
    int i = 0;
    float max = Mathf.Max(arr);
    float maxval = 10;
    foreach(float ele in arr)
    {
        arr[i] = (ele / max) * maxval;
        Debug.Log(arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

if the arr is [-5f , 10f, 20f]
it returns [-2.5f, 5f, 10f]

i expect it to be in range of 0 and 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a preset method to do that but you could try using the InverseLerp method from the original array and then use Lerp method to set new array, something like this:

```
float[] arr = new float[] { 5f ,10f ,20f };
float rangeMin = 0, rangeMax = 10; //these are the values you want to scale down (or up) the original array

float arrayMin = Mathf.Min(arr);
float arrayMax = Mathf.Max(arr);

for(int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++)
{
    var scaledDownValue = Mathf.InverseLerp(arrayMin, arrayMax, arr[i]);
    scaledDownValue = Mathf.Lerp(rangeMin, rangeMax, scaledDownValue);
    arr[i] = scaledDownValue;
}
```

Not tested, but inverseLerping it then Lerping it should help.

Comment: it is working thanks, do u have any idea how to reverse this operation